# How do I get the PodSpec of a replication controller using kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

How can I output the PodSpec of a replication controller using kubectl?

I tried

`kubectl describe rc <name>`

but the output doesn't include the PodSpec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the `pod.spec` for a replicationController using `kubectl get` and the `--output=json` or `--output-yaml` arguments. Something like this should work:

```
kubectl get rc <rc_name> --output=yaml
```

Comment: And to shorten things a little bit, you can just use `-o`, as in `kubectl get rc <rc_name> -o yaml`